# How can I check a filename suffix against a lot of options tersely?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program that essentially divides different file types among different directories. My computer does have many different image file types, so it makes a very long line in my code:

```
if file.name.endswith(".jpg") or \
   file.name.endswith(".JPG") or \
   file.name.endswith(".jpeg") or \
   file.name.endswith(".JPEG") or \
   file.name.endswith(".heic") or \
   file.name.endswith(".HEIC") or \
   file.name.endswith(".png") or \
   file.name.endswith(".PNG") or \
   file.name.endswith(".avif") or \
   file.name.endswith(".AVIF"):
```

I tried putting all the file type strings into a list and using the `any()` function but the problem is that any() gives a boolean output, while the `file.name.endswith()` function requires a str input.

Any ideas on how to simplify this line?

Comment: Adding to @kindall comment: get familiar with `help()` in the interactive shell. It provides information about methods like `str.endswith()`.

Comment: Please try to write a question title so other people with the same problem can tell if the question's answers will help them _without_ needing to click through and read the body. Our goal here is to build a FAQ; ideally, once we answer a question once for somebody, we should never need to answer it again for anyone else. I've attempted to edit towards that end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.path.splitext()` can split the extension off a filename, and using `lower()` can avoid the need to handle differently-cased variants separately:

```py
valid_extensions = set(['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.heic', '.png', '.avif'])

def check_extension(filename):
    return os.path.splitext(filename)[1].lower() in valid_extensions
```

This works as:

```
>>> check_extension('good.JPEG')
True
>>> check_extension('bad.zip')
False
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on your use of `file.name`, I'm guessing `file` is probably a [Path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) object. If so, in addition to the `name` attribute, it also has a `suffix` which contains the file extension (and `stem`, which is the part of the filename *before* the extension and can come in handy for other things). Once you have the suffix, you can lower-case it and check for its membership in a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) (which is more efficient than checking membership in, for example, a list).

```
if file.suffix.lower() in {'.jpg', '.jpeg', '.heic', '.png', '.avif'}:
```

Answer (score 1):

`str.endswith()` accepts a tuple of strings and any match is `True`. Also use `str.lower()` so you don't need to check for upper and lower case separately.

```
if file.name.lower().endswith((".jpg", ".jpeg", ".heic", ".png", ".avif")):
```